# Как определить разрядность процессора на C++ в Windows

Tags: c++, windows

Имеем 64-битный процессор с установленной Windows 7 x32.
Попытки воспользоваться кодом:

```
SYSTEM_INFO SI;
::GetNativeSystemInfo
switch( SI.wProcessorArchitecture )
```

выдают результат на приведенной архитектуре PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL, что по MSDN соответствует x32, т.е. результат - битность ОС, а не процессора.

Реализацию посредством WMI не предлагать!!!

Comment: смотрите переменную `%PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER%`

Comment: PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER: 

    x86 Family 6 Model 37 Stepping 5, GenuineIntel

и как это поможет?

Answer (score 2):

Необходимо проверить наличие флага EM64T/AMD64 (29-й бит) регистра EDX инструкции cpuid  0x80000001